# replace any line that starts with the symbol @ using sed, awk, cut

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut, fastq

this is simple but I was hoping for a quick command (using sed, cut, awk or something in BASH preferably) to do this:

replace any line that starts with the symbol @:

```
@<text, on one line, including numbers, letters and colons>
```

with

```
@<text, on one line, including numbers, letters and colons>/1
```

The `@` is always consistent, the `<text, on one line, including numbers, letters and colons>` changes. (It's Fastq format for the bioinformaticians out there).

Example:

```
@HWI-D00193:58:H73UEADXX:1:1101:1516:2209 1:N:0:ATCACG
```

change to

```
@HWI-D00193:58:H73UEADXX:1:1101:1516:2209 1:N:0:ATCACG/1
```

I know this is simple sorry.

Comment: came upon this while looking for more broader question: how to replace whole line, which is answered [here](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/System-Administration/Replace-whole-line-using-sed-or-awk/td-p/4849415) with `cat file | sed 's/^.*STRING_TO_BE_REPLACED.*$/LINE_TO_REPLACE_WITH/' >new_file`

Comment: Funnily, came here also looking for conversion of FASTQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`, you can do as below:

```
sed "/^@/ s/$/\/1/g" file
```

This matches lines that start with `@` and then appends (*substitution at the end* to be precise) the `/1` on all the matching lines.

Comment: Wonderful thanks.. works for me.. Is the syntax: "/^@/ (matches any line starting with @)   s/$/\/1/g"  (appends /1)?

Comment: Yes. It'll append to any line starting with `@`. But won't append to lines where `@` may appear at other positions except at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk '/^@/ {$0=$0"/1"}1' file
```